# What is the migration guide for upgrading jhipster app from @4.2.0 to @4.6.2

Tags: jhipster

If you don't care about the story that`s ok, just go to the question marked with bold font.

I have corrupted my project generated files. 
I can start my project from my ide as a spring boot app, but i can`t use "mvnw" file goals, and i don't know how to deploy my project without it.

What i decided to do is to generate another jhipster project and copy with replacement all files that was altered by me.

Problem is i have generated my starting project using jhipster version of 4.2.0. 
And when i tried to downgrade the jhipster version back to 4.2.0 with command

```
yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster@4.2.0
```

"jhipster" command stops being recognized in cmd and i have to use "yo jhipster" which results in the fact that  newly generated projects have the same problem as mine, i don`t understand why tho.

So i decided to generate project with latest version of jhipster and it works (yeay!), but only before i copy my webapp components into it.

**Important stuff** 
How do i migrate my project to the newer version?

It seams that there have bean quite a lot of changes in the way jhipster angular 4 app is generated.
Here are some changes i have spotted that require changes in my files.

1) The changes that i have immediately spotted is that services located in ng-jhipster module have bean given a 'Jhi' prefix in their names.

2) There seams to be a change in the way popup window components are called. I have not quite understand quite how yet so explanations are needed and encouraged.

Comment: @Gaël Marziou yes

Comment: We have found a bug in jhipster upgrade on Windows https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6161 a fix should be relased soon. This regression for Windows was introduced in 4.6.1. So maybe you could try to upgrade to 4.6.0.

Comment: jhipster cli was introduced in 4.5.0 (https://jhipster.github.io/2017/05/20/jhipster-release-4.5.0.html) but you can still use yo jhipster

Comment: Say Whaaat ? Jhipster can update itself, i had no idea. Hmm, i do have a linux installed on my computer. So if i execute upgrade from there it should be fine?

Comment: Better than on Windows for sure. BTW, it could be time to read the docs https://jhipster.github.io/upgrading-an-application/

Comment: yah, i sorry i know i have definitely annoyed you a little to much, i just did not notice it, thanks a lot man